# How to push data from nested array to collectionVIew in tableVIewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My layout consists out of collectionviews with posters and those collectionviews are in tableviewcells
I load my data from the internet to Array>. The first array is for the tableviewcell, the second one is for the collectionview and then there's the struct with the URL to the poster. I always get error out of index.

I'm a newbie in iOS developing so any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
struct TVShowTitle {
    var id: Int
    var posterPath: String
}

class ForYouViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var tvShowIds: Array<Array<TVShowTitle>> = [[TVShowTitle]]()
var section = 0

var sectionNames = ["Comedy Blockbusters", "Exciting TV", "Horror", "Popular shows", "Sci-fi", "TV Dramas", "Thrillers"]

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return sectionNames.count;
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionCell", for: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell

    section = indexPath.row

      cell.sectionNameLabel.text = sectionNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
      return cell;
  }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getTitlesForMostOfTheSections()
}

func getTitlesForMostOfTheSections() {
    // The function loads the URLs for the posters
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

extension ForYouViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    if tvShowIds.count <= section && indexPath.row <= tvShowIds[section].count {
             cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300" + tvShowIds[section][indexPath.row].posterPath))
        } else {
             cell.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")
        }
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      // How many shows in a section
    if section > tvShowIds.count || tvShowIds.count == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return tvShowIds[section].count
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to replace index.row with index.section here cell.sectionNameLabel.text = sectionNames[indexPath.row]

Comment: Where are you getting the error? In tableView's `cellForRowAt`? Or in collectionView's `cellForItemAt`? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @DonMag In collectionView’s cellForItemAt

Comment: @DonMag UPDATE: I get the error in collectionView’s cellForRowAt if I remove the if and else clause and just run the code from the if clause. Otherwise it only loads the placeholders

Comment: OK - you are doing a few things wrong. In particular, you should make your Table View Cell class the CollectionView DataSource and Delegate. Then when you create each cell in your table, you assign only *that row's* array of TVShows to the cell, and the cell supplies the data/images to its collection view. I'd suggest you read through this article - it's a good example of what you are trying to do: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/ (note: not my article, just one I've seen before)